# c# How to add data into existing collection item

Tags: c#, list, foreach

I am trying to add data to an existing List item. Currently I have two different collections. This is a subset of what I am working with and what I am trying to achieve.

```
List<Products> products = new List<Products>();
List<Fitment> fitment = new List<Fitment>();


  class Fitment
{

    public string Sku { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set;  }
    public string Years { get; set; }
  
}

class Products
{

    public string Sku { get; set; }
    public string Price { get; set;  }
    public string Vendor { get; set; }
  
}
```

What I need to do is match the SKU from the fitment list and add it to the item with the same SKU in the products list. One product can have several fitments (for example, a car seat that is used in multiple vehicles). The products list has 100k+ items and the fitment list has 400k+ items so I am looking for the fastest method to do this. I have tried several methods that time extremely long to process. What is the fastest way?

Comment: `I have tried several methods that time extremely long to process.` Please show us two of them. Also, how long is "extremely long"?

Comment: The standard solution for this would be a `Dictionary` (or `ConcurrentDictionary`) keyed by the SKU (or `BinarySearch` on an ordered list).

Comment: Shouldn't `Products` have a property with a collection of `Fitment`? Also, where is this data coming from? It'd probably make more sense to do this aggregation during the creation of these objects, instead of afterwards

Comment: You haven't indicated if the lists are ordered or not.  But regardless, this simply isn't going to be "fast", no matter what, unless you change the data structure.

Comment: @mjwills one being processing through the products collection with another loop inside to search for the associated sku in the fitment collection. That creates millions of loops and is extremely long. I will try to re-structure as a dictionary using the SKU as the key.

Comment: Also, how long is "extremely long"?

Comment: @mjwills the loops would take 15+ minutes to process it all.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem. I switched the Product to a Dictionary and used this to add the fitment data to the product data

```
productFitment.ForEach(fitment =>
           {
               if (dicProducts.ContainsKey(fitment.Sku))
                   dicProducts[fitment.Sku].ProductFitment.Add(fitment);
               else
                   Console.WriteLine(fitment.Sku);

           });
```